# Using ImagePickerController to get photo from library ok but navigating away then back to same view the image is gone

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to build a view where a user can select an image and it is retained within that view after navigating away from the view and coming back again. As a simple test app, I have created two view controllers. The first view controller has a forward button and uses a modal segue to go to the second view controller. The second view controller has a back button (modal segue back to first view controller) a Choose button and a Image button. So far I have configured the choose button to use the imagepickercontroller to select an image from the library and display onto the button which works no problem. The issue is that when i press the back button and the forward again back to the same screen the image isn't retained i have to reselect it. The intention is for the user to be able to take a picture or video of themselves performing an action and then select it within this app and have the picture displayed there for future reference.

My coding is as follows:

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *selectFromPhotoLibraryButton;
    IBOutlet UIButton *displayPictureButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *selectFromPhotoLibraryButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *displayPictureButton;

- (IBAction)selectPicture;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize selectFromPhotoLibraryButton;
@synthesize displayPictureButton;

-(IBAction)selectPicture
{
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:    (NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] retain];
    [displayPictureButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)  picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Please let me know if you require any of the other bits of code (its only the default app stuff, no further modification).

Comment: Hi all, just looking at my problem and what i need is exactly like when you select a picture for one of your contacts. You click the button, select choose, pick the image from camera roll and thats that. The image is there when I go in and out of that contact.

Comment: So does anyone have any ideas? I'm still working my way through this issue. Further investigation shows that the button used within the contacts app to display their picture is actually not a button but ABPersonImageView. So I guess what I'm trying to do is replicate this functionality within my app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As looking to your problem

I think you have to store selected image in NSUserDefault as archived data or something like that.

When u come back to second view then check first in NSUserDefault for image is saved or not.

If u got it then assign it to UIImage object by unarchiving.

As I have not implemented it so can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I've just set something like this up myself, I have the chosen image immediately placed in a UIImageView.

First, set up your view controller as a UIImagePickerDelegate:

```
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Then wherever you want to init the UIImagePicker, alloc, init and set its delegate to self:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And then I have the image picker storing the UIImage into the ImageView and also into the NSUserDefaults.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:    (NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] retain];
    [userDefaults setObject:image forKey:@"image"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self updatePreviewImage:image];
    }];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *) picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I hope this works for you, and anyone else that view this post.